# Python - Не работает asyncio: функции не работают асинхронно

Tags: python, асинхронность, asyncio

Не работает asyncio.
Функции выполняются без ошибок, но они не асинхронные.
Всё делал по гайду.
Вот код:

```
import asyncio

async def a():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("a")
async def b():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("b")

asyncio.run(a())
asyncio.run(b())
```

Вот ещё пример кода, в этот раз просто скопировал из документации:

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    print('Hello ...')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('... World!')
async def main2():
    print('Hello ...')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('... World!')

asyncio.run(main())
asyncio.run(main2())
```

Он тоже не работает (тоже без ошибок, но асинхронность не работает)

Comment: Не надо два раза использовать asyncio.run. Создается одна main и внутри нее запускаются две асинхронные функции. И только эту main запускают с помощью run

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации есть примеры. А как у вас примеров там всё же нет. Не надо два раза использовать asyncio.run. Создается одна main и внутри нее запускаются две асинхронные функции. И только эту main запускают с помощью run. Один из способов запустить конкурентно функции - использовать asyncio.gather. В этом случае будет дожидаться выполнение обеих запущенных конкурентно функций.

```
import asyncio
import time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    print("before")
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main():
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    await asyncio.gather(say_after(1, 'hello'),say_after(2,'world'))

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

asyncio.run(main())
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines